# I have two list of strings ['a','d','w','t'] & ['qq','ww','eee'] .I want to get the output as list of dictionary in a particular order?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have two list of strings `['a','d','w','t']` & `['qq','ww','eee']`.I want to get the answer in specific order in list of dictionary . It should be like

```
{'a':'qq','a':'ww','a':'eee','d':'qq','d':'ww','d':'eee',........,'t':'qq','t':'ww','t':'eee'}
```

Comment: ok it was a mistake i changed the brackets.can any help me ?

Comment: It's not a good dictionary either.  A key can only have one value.  You will discover that all your keys only have the value 'eee'.

Comment: How do you get duplicate keys in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

A python dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, you need to use a list of list or list of tuples. The following code gives you a list of tuples, in the order that you require:

```
list_1 = ['a','d','w','t']
list_2 = ['qq','ww','eee']
result = [(i, j) for i in list_1 for j in list_2]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'qq'), ('a', 'ww'), ('a', 'eee'), ('d', 'qq'), ('d', 'ww'), 
 ('d', 'eee'), ('w', 'qq'), ('w', 'ww'), ('w', 'eee'), ('t', 'qq'), 
 ('t', 'ww'), ('t', 'eee')]
```